# Ember unable to find view in internet explorer

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using old version of ember-cli (0.0.40) , do some changes without version updating, application works in chrome fine. but when I check it internet explorer 11 it throws error :

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Unable to find view at path 'wizard-menu'
```

here is log of application:

```
[ ] view:wizard-menu ........................................... scripts/wizard-menu/view
[ ] view:wizard-menu ........................................... undefined
[ ] view:wizard-menu ........................................... undefined
[ ] view:wizard-menu ........................................... scripts/views/wizard-menu
[ ] view:wizard-menu ........................................... scripts/wizard-menu/view
[ ] view:wizard-menu ........................................... undefined
[ ] view:wizard-menu ........................................... undefined
[ ] view:wizard-menu ........................................... scripts/views/wizard-menu
[ ] view:wizard-menu ........................................... undefined

SCRIPT5022: Error: Assertion Failed: Unable to find view at path 'wizard-menu'
File: vendor.js, Line: 13269, Column: 9
```

file is located in following path:

> ....\Scripts\app\views\wizard-menu.js

I use view helper in template :

```
{{view "wizard-menu" }}
```

and inside app.js i define prefix :

```
import Resolver from 'ember/resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers';

Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS = true;
var App = Ember.Application.extend({
    modulePrefix: 'scripts', 
    Resolver: Resolver
});
loadInitializers(App, 'scripts');
export default App;
```

And in my index.cshtml file I use scripts with the following code :

```
<script>
    window.ScriptsENV = { "baseURL": "/", "locationType": "hash", "EmberENV": { "FEATURES": {} }, "APP": { "LOG_RESOLVER": true, "LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION": true, "LOG_MODULE_RESOLVER": true, "LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS": true }, "LOG_MODULE_RESOLVER": true };
    window.EmberENV = window.ScriptsENV.EmberENV;
</script>
<script>
    window.Scripts = require('scripts/app')['default'].create(ScriptsENV.APP);
</script>
```

Comment: Could it be because your folder `Scripts` has its first letter in upper case?

Comment: Scripts is a folder name, where whole ember application is located , prefix which is defined in app.js file is lower case  :/

Comment: why shouldn't you just publish your ember project and then add it to your app?

Comment: what do you mean @shayanypn?

Comment: @Nininea do you want to use and ember app within you .net app?

Comment: Yeap, I use ember app inside .net application, generaly it works fine

Comment: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/issues/74 - I have found some questions, but not cleat, because my declaration works fine in chrome, but have problem in ie